# I setup jdk on my pc to test my java code on vs code but it doesn't work even on intellij program I faced the same? may I make a mistake in the path

Tags: java, intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, filepath

I think I made a mistake in putting the right path whether in vs code or intellij but how can isolve this problem? The setup version of jdk is 11.1.11 (adopeopenjdk)

Comment: In **intellij-idea community edition** you can go on `Create New Project`. In new window on top you have **Project SDK**.  Then you have option to choose version of java you used in previous projects, Download JDK, Browse(Add) JDK, or to use JDK detected on computer.

Comment: See the official JetBrains documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html#jdk on how to link JDK with the project.